# Java function to preserve the granularity

Tags: java, function, granularity

I need to keep the granularity in a fuzzy job so I made a function which receives as parameters:

- the granularity (a double between 0 and 1, 0 not included)
- the value to transform, if necessary (it's a double greater than 0)

And returns a new value with the correct granularity.

This is the function I have:

```
public static double preserveGranularity(double granul, double value){
    double integerValue= (double)(int)value;
    if(granul == 1)
        return integerValue;
    double decimal = value - integerValue;
    long factor = Math.round(decimal/granul);
    return integerValue + granul*factor;
}
```

Examples:

- preserveGranularity(0.25, 7.7) should return 7.75
- preserveGranularity(0.01, 0.009) should return 0.01

It runs good for most of values, but it doesn't for all (e.g.: preserveGranularity(0.2, 0.57)=0.6000000000000001, it should return 0.6)

Regards

P.S. Sorry for any mistake I made in this question, it's my first one here

Comment: There isn't really much of a difference between `0.6000000000000001` and `0.6`

Comment: Looks like a base 2->10 rounding error to me.

Comment: It's a minimum error, but it's causing problems. @Riking I think the same but how do I fix it?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot achieve this with `double` - since it is not exact enough.

`double`s are not real numbers. There are only finite number of bits to represent them - while there are infinite number of real (or even rational) numbers out there, so these rounding errors are expected.

I think you are looking for [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html), which lets you control the granularity, as you want, for example with its [`round()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#round%28java.math.MathContext%29) method.

Answer (score 1):

Floating point calculations are not exact (the computer can only represent so much digits).  This means that somewhere in your division/multiplication/rounding/subtraction/addition operations you lose precision.